# menu in android but without menu button

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to make a menu in my android app but I don't want that one which appears by pressing menu button, I just want it to be appeared without that.

Example :
This is Google maps app on android
I want to show such menu in the bottom while app is running without menu button.
I hope that someone got what I want exactly :)

[image: Google Maps app]

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you just need menu do the the following :

```
 public class Test extends ListActivity {
 String classes[] = { "first item", "second item", "third item", "fourth item"};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Test.this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, classes));
           }
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    String planet = classes[position];
    try {
        Class ourClass = Class.forName("com.test.test." + planet);
        Intent ourIntent = new Intent(Test.this, ourClass);
        startActivity(ourIntent);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
   }
```

this code will not create to you menu like the above image, but it will give you the standerd menu and you can customize it as you wish .
hope this helpful .

Answer (score 0):

You can yse [RelativeLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html) to do this. 
For example:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/icon" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking at is a Spinner that has been placed on an ActionBar.

Android's website has a tutorial on spinners that you can find at http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-spinner.html

Comment: If you read my post again, I meant the one in the bottom not the spinner menu in the top, BTW thanks a lot for your help, I was in need for that link too :) .

Comment: OH.  Thats just the overflow menu item on ICS devices.  (You mean the three vertical square dots, right?)  If thats the case, just populate your menu like normal and use an ActionBar.  The Overflow button will appear for devices that lack a menu button and it will display your normal menu items.

Comment: If you mean the menu thats in the middle of the page and want your own to display like that instead of a separate list, you'll want to take a glance at the Dialogs portion of the Developer Manual: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html

Comment: I know the overflow in the menu :) .. But I mean the menu itself without pressing a menu button .. Thanks for further info. about dialogs :)